# Given ∀x.∀y.p(x,y), use the Fitch System to prove ∀x.∀y.p(y,x)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In order to solve this question, I think I need to swap the two closed variables. I tried applying Universal Elimination in order to open up the closed variable but I don't know what to do after I reach- p(x,y).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: You need two fresh variables: $w,z$. Proof: $∀x∀y p(x,y) \vdash ∀y p(w,y) \vdash p(w,z) \vdash ∀y p(y,z) \vdash ∀x∀y p(y,x)$

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where it is clearest to use a Fitch-style system where we have to use a syntactically differentiated class of symbols for parameters (rather than re-cycle the same symbols for both [bound] variables and [unbound] parameters). For example, this is neat and clear:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\forall x\forall yPxy}
{\forall yPay\\
Pab\\
\forall yPyb\\
\forall x\forall yPyx} $

We instantiate the outer universal quantifier with a parameter at the second line, and then instantiate the quantifier at that line with a new parameter to get the third line. $a$ and then $b$ can be thought of as dummy names for arbitrarily chosen objects in the domain. Since they *are* arbitrary (don't appear in any assumption), we can then generalize (using any variable we like to form the universal quantifier) at the fourth line, and generalize again to get what we wanted at the fifth line. And so it goes.

If you use an (evil! ;) ND system that doesn't differentiate properly between bound variables and dummy names, then as Mauro says you'd need something that looks like

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\forall x\forall yPxy}
{\forall yPwy\\
Pwz\\
\forall yPyz\\
\forall x\forall yPyx} $

But to explain what that *means*, to explain what is going on here, you'll have to explain that $w$ and $z$ are playing a different role to the bound variables $x$ and $y$; and it is a good Fregean principle to use different styles of symbols for expressions playing different roles. That's why the first version of the proof, by those standards, counts as more logically perspicuous than the second version.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. However, I did not understand how to introduce the arbitrary variables.

Comment: @KeshavTiwari Which Fitch-style system are you using??? Always helps when asking a question like this to specify the particular book you are using (different books have different systems when it comes down to details!).

Comment: I'm using the classic Fitch Notation. I have reached here so far-   p([c1],X).

Comment: What is "classic Fitch Notation"??? A notation isn't a proof system. And as I said, different books using Fitch-style proof layouts use different deduction rules. So which book are you using?

Comment: David Barker-Plummer, Jon Barwise, and John Etchemendy. CSLI Publications, Stanford, CA, USA, 2nd edition.

Comment: Then they use *essentially*  the first proof I gave -- but have a different layout, using indentation when parameters are introduced. Some books do (theirs), some don't (mine).  That's a stylistic choice of no very deep significance. Though [in the edition I have] they have to messily allow multiple instantiations at once and multiple quantifications at once to allow the sort of inference you want.